# Some problems with scrolling Item inside Rows

Tags: ios, swift, collections, scroll

I have **collectionView** inside **tableView**. **collectionView** need to horizontal scroll image, **tableView** for vertical scroll posts. When I had 3 **rows** I had no problems, but when i create 4 **rows** i have a problem with scrolling **items** inside rows. If I start scrolling on 4 **row**, scrolling is repeated on **row** 1 and the same thing if i start scrolling on 1 **row** scrolling is repeating on **row** 4.

What could be the problem and how to solve it? May be

Can check .gif file. I start on 1 **row** on name "**Oko**" and if i scrolling down on 4 **row** and scroll right **collectionCell** and **return** on 1 **row** i see next image name "City", but there must be name "**Oko**"

My code:

**ViewController:**

```
class PhotoStudiosViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var theStudios: [Studio] = [] 
    var filteredStudios: [Studio] = [] 

    var studiosRef: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 475
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        studiosRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "PhotoStudios1")

        studiosRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for imageSnap in snapshot.children {

                let studioObj = Studio(snapshot: imageSnap as! DataSnapshot)

                self.theStudios.append(studioObj)

            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

    }
    // MARK: - TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {

            return filteredStudios.count

        }

        return theStudios.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoStudiosTableViewCell

        cell.currentPageNumber.text = "1/\(theStudios[indexPath.row].halls.count)"

        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != nil {
            cell.theHalls = filteredStudios[indexPath.row].halls
        } else {
            cell.theHalls = theStudios[indexPath.row].halls
        }

        cell.nameLabel.text = theStudios[indexPath.row].studioName

        cell.addressLabel.text = theStudios[indexPath.row].studioAddress

        cell.logoLabel.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: theStudios[indexPath.row].studioLogo))

        cell.didSelectAction = {

            (innerPath) in

            self.showDetailsView(indexPath, cellPath: innerPath)

        }

        return cell

    }
```

**TableViewCell:**

```
class PhotoStudiosTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var logoLabel: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentPageNumber: UILabel!

    var didSelectAction: ((IndexPath) -> ())?

    var theHalls: [Hall] = []

    var lastContentOffset = CGPoint.zero 

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        resetCollectionView()

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        currentPageNumber.layer.zPosition = 2
        currentPageNumber.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        currentPageNumber.clipsToBounds = true    

    }

    func resetCollectionView() {
        guard !theHalls.isEmpty else { return }
        theHalls = []
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - CollectionView
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return theHalls.count

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoStudiosCollectionViewCell2

        cell.hallName.text = theHalls[indexPath.item].hallName

        cell.priceLabel.text = theHalls[indexPath.item].hallPrice

        cell.metrslabel.text = theHalls[indexPath.item].hallMetrs

        cell.photoStudioImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: theHalls[indexPath.item].hallImage))

        return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        didSelectAction?(indexPath)

    }

}
```

[image: git image]

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems to be a problem of reuse. In other words, after scroll back to top the cell at index 1 is decorated with object from the fourth position. 
Take a look over your data source, it may be modified while scrolling or the cellForRowAtIndexPath: did not correctly decorate the cell.

Comment: I was thinking about reuse. But i don't understand what to do with it. Can you help me? If need my code i will add in question

Comment: The code may be helpufl, I will look tomorow on it.

Comment: i added viewController and tableViewCell, I hope this is enough

Comment: can help me with my question?

Comment: I don’t know what to say more than @mika. You can also try to call collectionView.reloadData() after you decorate the table view cell.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your cell does not reload its collectionView when var theHalls is set.

**Edit:**

You can modify your code like this:

```
var theHalls: [Hall] = [] {
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: most likely Yes, but i don't understand how to fix it

Comment: didn't help me :( apparently I have a more serious problem

Answer (score 0):

I was helped by this line of code added in **tableView** in method **cellForRow**

```
cell.collectionView.contentOffset = .zero
```